# How to pass pointers correctly for custom class

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

The backPtr_ of last node is pointing to itself at the time of generating trajectory.
This is mostly happening due to the backptr__ is pointing at the back of openNodes and while exploring a node it is last element due to pop_heap.
Any work around for this?

I have already tried to keep the openNodes as vector of Node objects rather than of pointers.

```
    init_node.calculateF();
    vector<Node*> openNodes;
    openNodes.push_back(&init_node);
    vector<vector<coord_t>> traj;
    while(!openNodes.empty()){
                pop_heap(openNodes.begin(), openNodes.end(), NodePtrCompareGtr());
                Node* newNodePtr = openNodes.back();
                Node newNode = *newNodePtr;
                openNodes.pop_back();
                traj = newNode.exploreNodes(openNodes, openSet, closedNodes, &newNode);
    }


    class Node
    {
        Node *backPtr_ = NULL;
        public:
        void setBackPtr(Node* nodeptr){
            backPtr_ = nodeptr;
        }

        vector<vector<coord_t>> exploreNodes(vector<Node*> &openNodes){
        newCoordList = generateCoords();
        vector<Node*> newNodeList;
        if(goal_reached(this)){
            return generate_traj(this);
        }
        for(auto const& newCoords : newCoordsList){
            Node *newNode = new Node(...);
            newNodeList.push_back(newNode);
        }
        for(auto & i : newNodeList){
            ...
            i->setBackPtr(this);
            openNodes.push_back(i);
            make_heap(openNodes.begin(), openNodes.end(), NodePtrCompareGtr());
            ...
        }
    }
```

I want to store the backPtr_ correctly to store the correct previous node.

Comment: It isn't clear al all what the purpose of backPtr_ is. What is is supposed to point at? If it's the owner of openNodes that has this node, then why not set backPtr_ right after adding your node to openNodes, and unset it right after removing it therefrom?

Comment: Better don't use raw pointers at all. C++ has the [smart pointer facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) which enables you to do such stuff way more painlessly. Also regarding linked lists, it's not necessary to reinvent the wheel, you can simply use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  The code is not for linked list but a variation of A*. I know that A* has been implemented too but the variation I am doing has not been. I'll try learning about the smart pointers.

Comment: @n.m. backPtr_ is supposed to keep track of the previous node for generating final trajectory. I also have one other need for it due to which can't unset it on reaching that node.